# Is learning Drupal 7 a bad option now after release of Drupal 8

Tags: 7

Hi I am WeB developer and have recently started  learning drupal 7.
I have finished learning basics of PHP and have started learning drupal along with learning how to program the individual elements. Thankfully i have also got no. of materials ranging from books and video tutorials but what i also find is Drupal 8 has now also been released though i think it will take a lot of lot of time for people to build learning materials for that.

But i also think that it will take atleast 1.5 years to learn entire aspect of drupal and by that time Drupal 8 will be the worldwide adopted version.So do you guys think that learning Drupal 7 will be a waste as ppl will sign it off by then due to advent of Drupal 8.
Please guide me on the same

Comment: Drupal 8 will still use the hook system and views so its still a good idea to use them.

Comment: Not at all. Drupal 8 need a long time to be fully practical. Lots of modules need to be compatible with the Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly learning never gets wasted. Whatever you learn will some day in some moment help you.

Yes, Drupal 8 is going to be released and not yet released. No one knows when it gets released and even people are skeptic about the features that vary with Drupal 7. Definitely, Drupal 8 is going to set a new standard in development and usage. But, till then we shouldn't avoid Drupal 7.

Previously, we developed a website in Drupal 6 as soon as we deployed the site Drupal 7 was released. Then the features provided by Drupal 7 attracted us and we started migrating to 7 and it took most of our time in migrating. But our knowledge and work in drupal 6 didn't go into vain. Infact, we just learnt the new features added/upgraded. It took us only 1-2 days to know about Drupal 7, as we know the core concepts.

So, I suggest you to start learning drupal 7 don't bother about the things that are yet to come. You can easily manage things even drupal 8 gets released.

Answer (score 0):

learning never gets wasted, most of the major principle remains same for Drupal 8. you will get more exposure learning many things and learn how to things different ways.

Yes, Drupal 8 is releasing soon, you can take all the benefits of core modules, but if you want more features and extended functionality you have to use contributed modules and not much contributed modules are there for Drupal8, developer needs time to write those modules for drupal8, you have to wait for that as well.

Decision is yours. I suggest you to go with Drupal7 and keep learning drupal8 as well.